# Function whose power series coefficients contain logarithms

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

Is there a function that can be expressed as a power series

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$$

whose coefficients $a_n$ are expressions containing $\log n$ or something similar?

Comment: I think you mean to say: "is there a 'standard' / 'simple' / 'elementary' etc. function...like $\sin(x)$" Otherwise,  $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (\log n) x^n$ will do!  I do not know of any nice examples.

Comment: It would be a function on its own.

Comment: @Winther You'd have to start from $n=1$ though.

Comment: @oliveeuler Hehe, of course!

Comment: @Winther Correct. Special functions like the Gamma function, error function, or beta function also count.

Comment: @oliveeuler Right, the expression should contain something of the form $\log (n+1)$ instead.

Comment: the coefficient of $x^n$ in the Taylor series of $$f(x)=-\frac{\log(1-x)}{1-x}$$ around zero is $H_n$, the $n$-th harmonic number, that is pretty much tha same as $\log n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a non-elementary example arising from zeta functions.

Consider the polylogarithm $\text{Li}_s(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{x^n}{n^s}$. Since $n^{-s}=\exp(-s \ln n)$, differentiation with respect to $s$ yields
$\partial_s\text{Li}_s(x)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln n\,\dfrac{x^n}{n^s}$.

Note in particular that $x\to 1$ gives the first derivative of the Riemann zeta function; the limit $s\to 0$ thus yields $\zeta'(0)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln n$ (in the sense of analytic continuation in complex $s$.

Comment: So the regularized sum of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\log n=-\zeta'(0)=\frac{1}{2}\log(2\pi)$?

Comment: Yes. Note that that implies the zeta-regularized product $\infty ! = \sqrt{2\pi}$.